# How to add transparent images (logo) in html website; I have tried but the white background appears in website, How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, background, transparent

I am a noob
Just practicing
adding a transparent logo to my website
but the white background appears behind the logo
How to fix it?  this is the link of image -   https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/13-130171_avengers-png-logo-free-transparent-png-logos-rh.png

```
     This is the html & css code
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<img class=image src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/13-130171_avengers-png-logo-free-transparent-png-logos-rh.png">
```

Comment: probably because your image has no transparency.

Comment: The image you are using isn't transparent, it just has the checker box effect that a lot of image editors use to indicate a transparent background as the actual background.

Comment: See my post below where I mentioned Paint.Net. Open your image with Paint.Net. Then choose the Select Wizard and click somewhere on the image (not on the letters). Then press the Delete button on your keyboard. Then save as 32 bits png file. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

That's not working because the image isn't actually the transparent - the background looks as if it is transparent, but actually the background *is* the transparent-looking design.

Comment: In Paint.Net, simply choose Layers > Layer property > Opacity level. Any image can be made transparent this way in 256 transparancy gradients.

Comment: how do we know it ?

Answer (score 0):

PNG images usually has transparent background, sometimes it doesn't work(i dont know why). Already happened to me. When this happens I use the photoshop and select what a need and convert to png again. It worked. I know this is not the answer you want, but it was what i did to find a solution. Good Luck!

Comment: Transparacy does work if the png has been saved as 32 bits png image.

Answer (score 0):

On websites, the PNG format is the one you need for 4 important reasons:

- supported in **all** browsers
- great compression for smaller file size.
- 16 million colors
- 256 transparancy levels (0-255)

To create a new image OR edit an existing image to give it transparancy, you have to use a Paint program, for example the easy to use and free Paint.Net https://www.getpaint.net . In this program you can use effects for transparancy OR the opacity slider OR the color palette to choose transparancy.

**Important**: in the 'Save as' dialog, choose the 32 bits PNG file. This means that you have 8 bits red, 8 bits green, 8 bits blue and 8 bits for transparancy.

- 256 x 256 x 256 = 16 million colors.
- 256 gradients of transparancy.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<img class=image src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/13-130171_avengers-png-logo-free-transparent-png-logos-rh.png">
```

In img tag or in your image class just give the property

**`mix-blend-mode: multiply;`**

after applying thihs property if you are not getting the result than you may have to change your image!!

Thanks for voting, hope this helps to you.